# animating (fadein) a jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I have some header text which changes when any four links are clicked using the `.text` property

now i need to animate it when mouseout(mouse hovers out) , can someone put this together ?

```
$('#clickdiv').mouseout(function(){
       $('#header').text('new text');

  });
```

and

```
$('#header').fadeIn(2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#clickdiv').mouseout(function(){
       $('#header').text('new text');
       $('#header').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

or

```
$('#clickdiv').mouseout(function(){
       $('#header').text('new text').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: @user1749105 `fadeIn()` is pretty straight-forward.  what about his code is _not_ working?  It's so simple..that seems impossible.. +1

Comment: my bad ! works perfect !

Comment: @user1749105 make sure you **accept** the answer.  (click the checkmark) and welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: yes sir! excuse my noobness

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aTWsg/ please see if fade out is working . isnt working although fade out work

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your some of HTML, because its very difficult to get idea,

http://jsfiddle.net/UDgTK/2/

```
$('#clickdiv').mouseout(function(){
       $('#header').fadeIn(2000);
}); ​
```

Comment: the above answer by http://stackoverflow.com/users/1235698/webnetmobile-com works !

Comment: +0 because while this is correct, it _should_ be a comment.

Comment: please correct if possible @mmmshuddup http://jsfiddle.net/aTWsg/

Comment: @user1749105 that script shows me that you don't fully understand the role of `id` vs `class` in HTML/CSS.  Anyway, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/aTWsg/5/

Comment: yes i am a little confused between the two . any links you could share that would help me in the right direction ? and thanks for the correction much appreciated !